# The 2k+ inline editor doesn't seem to work anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, inline-editor

There's not really much to say about it aside from the title. The 2k+ inline editor used to work, now it doesn't. The edit link now goes to the full edit page instead, and it did happen somewhat late (in +2 GMT anyway) today.

Aside from me, it has been reproduced by at least [some other users in SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/49103262#49103262).

The 10k+ tag editor still works though, so it only affects the inline post editor.

Comment: Confirmed on this very post.

Comment: Can confirm for me too, at least in the latest version of Firefox. Another user using Chrome didn't experience the issue.

Comment: @V2Blast could be a caching/staged rollout thing. I got it after some people in SOCVR for an instance. Firefox here too btw, but I'm gonna try to repro in Chrome later For Science:tm:

Comment: Reproduced in Chromium (latest version, x64 Linux) too.

Comment: On MSO: *[Inline editor is no longer available: cannot exit out of edit mode with ESC or by clicking the question title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396588)*

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - I recommend the [tag:featured] tag. :-)

Comment: Not really what it's for. That said, this seems a great example of the review tag at work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should be fixed now. I had reversed the logic in a ternary. Thank you for finding it!

Comment: [Can confirm it works](https://i.imgur.com/TZ4Eioa.png). Thanks! ^^

Comment: So who did have the inline editor during this? If it's a ternary, someone should have it.

Comment: Thank you for fixing this! :)